# Flux.jl restrict variables between 0 and 1

Tags: deep-learning, julia

I would like each item in my output feature vector to be between 0 and 1 (The truth vector is a bunch of independent binary values). Eventually, with training it approaches this but I assume there is a way to restrict the variable to a range, thus allowing it to converge more quickly.

This is NOT [softmax](https://fluxml.ai/Flux.jl/stable/models/nnlib/#Softmax-1). softmax turns a vector into a distrubution which sums to one but I want each item in the vector to be restricted to the range 0 - 1.

Answer (score 2):

Constraints like this can be added by utilizing an activation function on the last layer. Add a sigmoid on the output to make it in [0,1]. Add exp on the last layer to make it [0,infty). Etc.

Comment: Thank you, that was as easy as I'd hoped. I'm just somewhat self-taught on ML right now so there are plenty of gaps in my knowledge.