# Flux.jl model always outputs 1.0 after adding Sigmoid activation function

Tags: julia, flux.jl

My original issue was that I wanted my model to only output 0-1 so I can map back to my categorical images labels ([Flux.jl restrict variables between 0 and 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61536132/flux-jl-restrict-variables-between-0-and-1)). So I decided to add a sigmoid activation function as follows:

```
σ = sigmoid

model = Chain(
  resnet[1:end-2],
  Dense(2048, 1000),  
  Dense(1000, 256),
  Dense(256, 2, σ),        # we get 2048 features out, and we have 2 classes
);
```

However, now my model only outputs 1.0. Any ideas as to why or if I am using the activation function wrong?

Comment: Can you expand your question by defining resnet so that one can rerun your code in the same way as you?

Comment: The code is based off of: https://fluxml.ai/tutorials/2020/10/18/transfer-learning.html I can link the full code if need be but it's similar to this tutorial

Answer (score 1):

Consider to use an activation function for your hidden layers as multiple linear layers (Dense layers without a non-linear activation function) are just equivalent to a single linear layer. If you are using categories which are exclusive (dog or cat, but not both) which cover all your cases (it will always be a dog or cat and never e.g. an ostrich) then the probabilities should sum to one and a `softmax` should be more appropriate for the last function.
The `softmax` function is generally used with the `crossentropy`
loss function.

```
model = Chain(
  resnet[1:end-2],
  Dense(2048, 1000, σ),  
  Dense(1000, 256, σ),
  Dense(256, 2),
  softmax        
);
```

For better numerical stability and accuracy, it is recommended to replace `crossentropy` by and `logitcrossentropy` respectively (in which case `softmax` is not necessary).

Comment: This gives an error: `MethodError: no method matching similar(::Float32, ::Type{Float32})
Closest candidates are:
  similar(!Matched::Union{LinearAlgebra.Adjoint{T, var"#s814"}, LinearAlgebra.Transpose{T, var"#s814"}} where {T, var"#s814"<:(AbstractVector{T} where T)}, ::Type{T}) where T at /Users/julia/buildbot/worker/package_macos64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.6/LinearAlgebra/src/adjtrans.jl`

Comment: @logankilpatrick, indeed, I updated my reply by putting softmax after the last Dense layer. Does it work now?

Comment: It seems to restrict values between 0 and 1 but the output values are always the same for different images

Comment: @logankilpatrick Are you sure that the ResNet model is actually pre-trained? It is mentioned as not pre-trained in the docs (https://fluxml.ai/Metalhead.jl/dev/README.html) If not, you need to train all parameters of the model and possibly for more than just 2 epochs. As a test, you can also run the full ResNet model with your tests data.

Comment: That is probably the issue, let me try training all the layers.

Comment: I updated the model to re-train all the layers but the result seems to be the same

Comment: You can find the code for this here: https://github.com/logankilpatrick/DeepLearningWithJulia/blob/main/src/transfer_learning.ipynb maybe I am doing something wrong?